# Need to sum up the total amount and create order summary in another intent/activity

Tags: java, android

[XML LAYOUT SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyu75.png)
Trying to calculate the final amount of selected items in an another activity. Need to create order summary in another activity.

Tried introducing multiplication function but also need to hard code the quantity values to auto calculate the final amount.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText pantqty;
EditText pantrate;
TextView result;
Button SUBMIT;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pantqty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pantqty);
    pantrate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pantrate);
    SUBMIT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.et_submit);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_result);


    SUBMIT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int q = Integer.valueOf(pantqty.getText().toString());
            float r = Integer.valueOf(pantrate.getText().toString());
            float amount = q * r;
            result.setText(Float.toString(amount));
        }
    });

}
}
```

Need to create a method in OnCLickListener to calculate the amount from the items selected.can if else case be used on OnclickListerButton?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Soory didn't understand your problem. Could you please explain a bit more clearly?

Comment: Please have a look into the screenshot.
i first success fully multiplied the pant_qty and pant_rate and displayed the final amount in et_result(TextView)
But wat i needed was to do the same for varibale/Item "Shirt"...how can i do the same calculation with "SUBMIT" button without adding another button for Shirt Item. can we use if else case here..?? Thanks

Comment: Saw the screen shot. You need to find the total amount of both items. You are calculating the amount of pants on button click . This much I understood.Could you please tell what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: yes. creating a laundry system where "items" quantity is insert and when "SUBMIT" button is click a new activity pops up displaying the "ORDER SUMMERY".

Comment: like 2 pants, 3 shirt and so on.
once SUBMIT is clicked the final order summery shows up.
thanks!!

Comment: So you want to show final Price in the new activity. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, but also need to calculate the Shirt as well. Right now only able to calculate the pant section. I have uploaded a new screenshot..please have a look once..Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText pantqty;
EditText pantrate;
EditText shirtQty;
EditText shirtRate;
TextView result;
Button SUBMIT;


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 pantqty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pantqty);
 pantrate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pantrate);
 shirtQty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shirtqtyId);
 shirtRate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shirtRateId);
 SUBMIT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.et_submit);
 result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_result);


 SUBMIT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
 calculateSum();
 }
 });

 }

private void calculateSum(){
int q=0;
String pantQty=pantqty.getText().toString().trim();
if(!pantQty.isEmpty() && pantQty!="") {
q=Integer.valueOf(pantQty);
}
float r = Integer.valueOf(pantrate.getText().toString());
int a = Integer.valueOf(shirtQty.getText().toString());
float b = Integer.valueOf(shirtRate.getText().toString());
float amount = (q * r)+(a*b);
result.setText(Float.toString(amount));
 Intent intent=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("total",amount);
 startActivity(intent);
}
    }
```

On the secondActivity you get get the total as:

```
float total=getIntent().getFloatExtra("total",0.0);
```

Comment: great. this seems to be resolving my problem.
Let me try. will get you informed once complied the code.
thanks for response!!!

Comment: If it solves your problem. Do accept and upvote the answer

Comment: hi methew, is there any variable have to be declared in SecondActivity.class. B'cus the second activity is appearing completely blank.

Comment: Can you post the code of Second Activity showing what you have done till now?

Comment: hi methew, very thanks for supporting all along.
Please do me one more favor...kindly review my down below code. 
And also the Second activity code where Order Summary is getting received.
Also attached the UI of an app. 
Much Appreciated .  Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Code looks fine. Just take care of naming your variable properly. refer some standard android naming documentations

Comment: I think  when (a*b) + (b*c) calculation is getting performed then app is crashing.
I have tried only multiplying two variables(a*b) and it works fine. But when Introduce Addition between the app is getting closed/crashing.

Comment: Can you post your log for the crash.

Comment: Please review the error. Its showing NumberFormatException.
Also check the LogCat.image attached

Comment: Hi,this exception is coming because one of your quantity field is empty i.e, there is no input value in that field. Hence it can't be parsed to an integer. One thing you can do is check for empty string before parsing it to an integer.

Comment: I am new in java. Could you please tel me how to do that.
Shell is go for ...try { Catch}

Comment: Try catch is an option but it would still be better if you use a default value or something. This case is arising because user hasn't entered any to your quantity field. I have updated the code to show a sample of how you can handle it. Please check it.

Comment: very well will try ASAP. Again thanks for the all support.

Comment: hi there methew, you are a code wizard for real. My code i working after the method u described.
Thanks a ton for an awesome support!!!!!!!!!
my final code is below. Again appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pantqty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lo_pantqty);
    shirtqty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lo_shirtqty);
    shareesqty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lo_shareesqty);
    suitqty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lo_suitqty);

    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_result);
    SUBMIT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.io_enter);

    SUBMIT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            calculationSum();
        }
    });

}

private void calculationSum() {

    int q = 0;
    String pantQTY = pantqty.getText().toString().trim();
    if (!pantQTY.isEmpty()&&pantQTY!=""){
        q = Integer.valueOf(pantQTY);
    }
  int r = 0;
  String shirtQTY = shirtqty.getText().toString().trim();
  if (!shirtQTY.isEmpty()&&shirtQTY!=""){
      r = Integer.valueOf(shirtQTY);
   }
    int a = 0;
    String suitQTY = suitqty.getText().toString().trim();
    if (!suitQTY.isEmpty()&&suitQTY!=""){
        a = Integer.valueOf(shirtQTY);
    }

   int b = 0;
  String shareesQTY = shareesqty.getText().toString().trim();
   if (!shareesQTY.isEmpty()&&shareesQTY!=""){
        b = Integer.valueOf(shirtQTY);
    }
    int amount = (q*30) + (r*35) + (a*220) + (b*60);
    result.setText(Integer.toString(amount));
}
```

}